# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

```
public class TestSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.println(". How are you?");
    }
}
```

When I compile this program, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

---

Also, why can't I have an `args` which accepts an int array like this:

```
public static void main(int[] args) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0**

It was thrown because `args.length == 0` therefore `args[0]` is outside the arrays range of valid indices ([learn more about arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)).

Add a check for `args.length>0` to fix it.

```
public class TestSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args.length>0 ? args[0] : " I don't know who you are");
        System.out.println(". How are you?");
   }
}
```

**2. Command line args as int**

You will have to parse the arguments to `int[]` yourself as the command line arguments are passed only as a `String[]`.  To do this, use [Integer.parseInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) but you will need exception handling to make sure the parsing went OK ([learn more about exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)).  Ashkan's answer shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

with regards to second part of your question:

from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html :

> Parsing Numeric Command-Line Arguments
>
> If an application needs to support a numeric command-line argument, it
>   must convert a String argument that represents a number, such as "34",
>   to a numeric value. Here is a code snippet that converts a
>   command-line argument to an int:
>
> ```
> int firstArg;
> if (args.length > 0) {
>     try {
>         firstArg = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
>     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>         System.err.println("Argument must be an integer");
>         System.exit(1);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

1. The error is because no arguments were added when the program started.
2. Since the signature of the called main method (by JVM) is `public static void main(String[] args)` and not `public static void main(int[] args)` if you want ints, you'll need to parse them from the arguments.