# How to pass command-line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line

I get the above error when I try to compile this simple program:

```
/* @author 
 * This program expects two command-line arguments
 * -- a person's first name and last name.
 * For example:
 * C:\Mywork> java Greetin Annabel Lee
 */
public class Greetin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String firstName = args[0];
        String lastName = args[1];
        System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.println("Congratulations on your second program!");
    }
}
```

From looking at other questions, I understand the error has something to do with `args == 0` and `0` being greater than the number, but I don't know how to fix the problem for this case.
Is there any way the error is also identified as being caused by the `void`?

Comment: Are you passing two arguments when you run the program? Which is line 12?

Comment: line 12 is the String firstName = args[0];

Comment: I guess I'm passing two argument b/c of the args[0] and args[1] firstname and lastname, respectively.

Comment: You're *expecting* two arguments. This doesn't mean you are necessarily *passing* two arguments when running the class. Are you definitely using `java Greetin Annabel Lee` as you have in your comment?

Comment: So how do I pass two arguments, is that why the error is occurring? Yes, I'm using java Greeting, Annabel Lee is just and example input.

Comment: "So how do I pass two arguments" -- `java MyApp argument1 argument2`

Comment: You may want to correct you problem statement from "I get the above error when I try to compile this simple program:" To "I get the above error when I try to *run* this simple program:"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386372/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0). There are many, but this one seemed the closest after looking through ten or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is there aren't any args supplied to your program. Good convention is to make sure the user inputs the expected amount of args, else die. In your case:

```
if( args.length != 2 ){
    System.out.println("usage: Greetin <firstName> <lastName>");
}
else{
    String firstName = args[0];
    String lastName = args[1];
    System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Congratulations on your second program!");
}
```

Also, make sure you type: `java Greetin Annabel Lee` after you compile to properly set the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, the fix helped, I'm beginning in java, so some of terminology is a bit foreign but I'll get used to it with some studying.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not passing two command-line arguments to your program. The error is telling you that the array `args` doesn't have any elements because index `0` is out of the valid bounds. Make sure to pass the arguments when running your program.

```
java Greetin Annabel Lee
```