# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception for program compiled using Java

Tags: java

I am new to java. My code is:

```
public class Hi {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args[2]);
        System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print(args[1]);
        System.out.print(", and");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.println(".");
    }
}
```

I get  the following exception upon running this program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Hi.main(Hi.java:5)
```

I would be glad to know why I had got this exception and how to resolve it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. And what command-line args have you passed in?

Comment: what are you passing while executing your program

Comment: Like, `java hi any_arguments`?

Comment: `java Hi Mango Orange Banana`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386372/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0)

Comment: `if (args.length < 3) chastiseUser();`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameters which is less than 3, thats why you are getting this error.

try like below command,

**java hi test test test**

Answer (score 0):

Either you dint passed command line arguments while executing the program or **args.length < 3**

Answer (score 0):

You would have got this exception if you had tried to run this program providing 2 or fewer arguments.

- `args[0]` will be the first index of the array.
- `args[1]` will be the second index.
- `args[2]` will be the third index of the array.

This is because array index starts with 0 and ends with n-1 for arrays in Java. (n is the size of the array).

**Command line way**

This program will run fine, if you run the program as
`java Hi Demo Test Argument`

Here `Demo` is at `args[0]`, `Test` is at `args[1]` and `Argument` is at `args[2]`.

**Using Eclipse IDE**

- Right click on the class file.
- Select `Run As` and select `Run Configurations`
- Double Click on `Java Application`
- Go to the `Arguments` tab and provide three arguments in the `Program
  Arguments` textarea separated by spaces as shown in the image below.
  [image]
- Now click on `Apply` and then on `Run`